# Improving PHP loop validation

Tags: php

I have a php script that performs validation I have a code block that sets up 4 fields that need the same validation. What I want to achieve is that instead in this code block, I can setup the key name, the display name and field type and below set codes which would then automatically validate the fields according to the rules set for each field type.

Here is the code block in question:

```
// key name => display name
$fields = [
        'firstName' => 'First Name',
        'lastName' => 'Last Name',
        'companyName' => 'Company Name',
        'companyAddress' => 'Company Address',
    ];
```

So in this block I want to setup the key name, display name and field type. Currently I just got the these four fields. Is there a way I can achieve what I desire?

Here is my full code:

```
function validate($formData)
{
    // Initiate Array
    $validationMSG = array(); // array to hold validation errors

    // what to validate (basics, i.e. required fields)
    // key name => display name
    $fields = [
            'firstName' => 'First Name',
            'lastName' => 'Last Name',
            'companyName' => 'Company Name',
            'companyAddress' => 'Company Address',
        ];

    //simple loop
    foreach($fields as $name => $display){
        if(empty($formData[$name])){
            $validationMSG[$name] = "${display} is required.";
        }
    }        

    //and NOW wee can perform some specific tests:

    $pname_exp = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,20}/';
    if(isset($formData['firstName']) && !preg_match($pname_exp, $formData['firstName'])){
        $validationMSG['firstName'] = 'First Name is not valid.';
    }
    if(isset($formData['lastName']) && !preg_match($pname_exp, $formData['lastName'])){
        $validationMSG['lastName'] = 'Last Name is required.';
    }    

    //removed company name and company address checks, because we are done with them in the loop.

    // Validate state
    if (!isset($formData['state'])) {
        $validationMSG['state'] = 'State is required.';
    }

    // Validate city
    if (!isset($formData['city'])) {
        $validationMSG['city'] = 'City is required.';
    }

    // Validate Zipcode - If Field is Empty
    if (!isset($formData['zipcode'])) {
        $validationMSG['zipcode'] = 'Zipcode is required.';
    }

    // Validate emailAddress
    if (!isset($formData['emailAddress'])) {
        $validationMSG['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';
    }

    // Check if emailAddress is a valid email address
    elseif (!filter_var($formData['emailAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $validationMSG['emailAddress'] = 'Email address is not valid.';
    }

    //Validate phoneNumber
    if (!isset($formData['phoneNumber'])) {
        $validationMSG['phoneNumber'] = 'Phone Number is required.';
    }

    //Validate phoneNumber
    elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9-\s]+$/D', $formData['phoneNumber'])) {
        $validationMSG['phoneNumber'] = 'Must be a valid phone number.';
    }


    // Validate message
    if (!isset($formData['message'])) {
        $validationMSG['message'] = 'Message is required.';
    }

    if (!empty($validationMSG)) {
        return $validationMSG;        
    }
    else {
        $captcha = checkCaptcha($formData['g-recaptcha-response']);
        if(!$captcha['isSuccess']){
        $validationMSG['captcha'] = 'ReCaptcha is required.';

        return $validationMSG;
        }

        //End of Validation Function
    }
}
//testing
$input = ['firstName' => 'John'];
$errors = validate($input);
var_dump($errors);
```

Comment: What do you mean by field type? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I would recommend converting the array to a value object based on activity and implement a common interface (`StartUserRecord implements Transport`) and use annotations on the properties that validate the types (`@Assert\NotBlank` or `@Assert\NotNull`, or custom ones). Then your `validate(Transport $message)` function runs the validation and gives you messages back. See Symfony Validator for examples: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints

Comment: @weegee for example, firstName and lastName would require the same type of validation but phoneNumber would require a different type of validation, same with emailAddress which would require even another type of validation. I want to specify those "types" in that code block.

Comment: Like string, int and email?

Comment: You would use type declarations for that: `public function setName(string $name)`, or in 7.4 property types: `public string $name;` This is the benefit of using classes. Email and phone numbers are constraints not types, so you would either need a custom class like `Email` or use a generic or custom email constraint (see the Symfony link I provided).

Comment: You could also use a tuple like `'firstName','First Name','string:not-empty'`. That seems a little simplistic to me, though, and using annotations documents the source class and can be decomposed with reflection..

Comment: @jucyva I'm at work and don't have time at the moment to generate an example using classes and types. Here's an example of creating passable closures that types inputs (your request to ensure strings and integers are given), as well as giving a direct method to validate in-place: https://3v4l.org/3NGKY

Comment: More evolved, allowing you to group activities. This moves you further towards being able to refactor more effectively (you're essentially prototyping your classes anonymously). https://3v4l.org/2HiQX I'll try to add it as an answer later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an approach like this. This is a starting point to write a better validation check in your loops:

```php
<?php
function validate($formData)
{
    // Initiate Array
    $validationMSG = array(); // array to hold validation errors

    // what to validate (basics, i.e. required fields)
    // key name => display name
    $fields = [
            'firstName' => [
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ],
            'lastName' => [
                'label' => 'Last Name',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ],
            'emailAddress' => [
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|email'
            ]
        ];

    //simple loop
    foreach($fields as $fieldName => $args) {
        $rules = explode('|', $args['rules']);
        foreach($rules as $rule)
        {
            if($rule == 'required' && (!isset($formData[$fieldName]) || empty($formData[$fieldName])))
            {
                $validationMSG[$fieldName][] = sprintf('%s is a required field.', $args['label']);
            }

            if((isset($formData[$fieldName]) && $rule == 'email') && !filter_var($formData[$fieldName], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $validationMSG[$fieldName][] = sprintf('%s must be a valid email.', $args['label']);
            }
        }
    }

    return $validationMSG;
}
```

This can be improved but the concept will get you started.

Comment: You actually have to validate the validation, meaning that all the constructs are intact. This is point-of-source validation and can become unwieldy over time, although as you suggest it's a decent starting point. I would refactor away from it quickly, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish agreed! But this approach is much better than what @ jucyva is currently doing.

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you provide me with a sample of your approach/suggestion please?

Comment: @Rehmat why would you move away from point of source validation? I am not using a framework such as laravel or symfony.

Comment: @jucyva Can you explain `source validation` a little more? I didn't suggest you to use any framework. That's pure PHP.

Comment: I said point of source validation; this is validating a construct by passing in it's literal value at the point of it's source, e.g., in a procedure you make an array and pass it in. A typed validation is using a class with known constructs.

Comment: @JaredFarrish if you can please provide an example of how you would approach this whenever you can I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @jucyva I've added a couple demos of an alternate technique in the question comments above. I'll have to make an answer later.

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry I am just missing your additions. Anyways, just please post the answer later. I appreciate it a lot, thanks.

Comment: @jucyva They're the last two comments I left directly under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do validation, while still having a format that can be promoted to a typed class (e.g., with namespace and dependency injection, etc) on a refactor. What I will show you is a way to acquire an object in such a way you can validate the message payload, based on a common naming construct.

First, create a regular php function called `userActions()`. This will be used to (globally or as an include where needed) call into and get these objects. This will return a closure.

```
function userActions(): \Closure { ... }
```

Next, you'll need to encapsulate your procedure. I recommend doing it like this:

```
$startUserRecord = static function(
    string $firstName, 
    string $lastName, 
    string $companyName, 
    string $companyAddress
) {
    return new class(...func_get_args()) {
        private $payload = [];
        private $firstName; 
        private $lastName;
        private $companyName;
        private $companyAddress;

        public function __construct(
            string $firstName, 
            string $lastName, 
            string $companyName, 
            string $companyAddress
        ) {
            $this->payload = func_get_args();

            $this->firstName = $firstName;
            $this->lastName = $lastName;
            $this->companyName = $companyName;
            $this->companyAddress = $companyAddress;
        }

        public function validate(): array {
            // Here is where you would actually validate this one message.
            // Empty array means no validation messages (errors).
            return [];
        }

        public function payload(): array {
            return $this->payload;
        }
    };
};

// Other ones go here, too.
$saveUserProfile = static function() { ... };
$resetUserLogin = static function() { ... };
```

Corral them up to together, so we can `use()` them in our `userActivities()` closure:

```
$activities= [
    'startUserRecord' => $startUserRecord,
    'saveUserProfile ' => $saveUserProfile,
    'resetUserLogin ' => $resetUserLogin,
];
```

Now, I've called it `startUserRecord` because I needed to make up a command name; give it the name you wish, however I recommend *verb + subject + context* construct, generally.

Static checks work for the "string, integer" and other low-level type checks, or class-based constructs as you have available (say, an `Email` value object). The validation of the values, as you can see, occurs inside the `validate()` method.

Next, create the closure that you'll return that actually allows you to search for and get only the command objects you want:

```
return static function(/* autoset as $get */) use($activities) {
    $get = func_get_args();

    $find = static function($name) use(&$get) {
        return in_array($name, $get);
    };

    $filtered = array_filter($activities, $find, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $found = [];

    // Keep in the same order.
    foreach($get as $name) {
        $found[] = $filtered[$name];
    }

    return $found;
};
```

Pay attention to the `use()` statement on the closure(s).

This is put within the `userActivities()` function declaration. Now, you can call and set it up, and generally use what you have:

```
$fields = [
    'firstName' => 'First Name',
    'lastName' => 'Last Name',
    'companyName' => 'Company Name',
    'companyAddress' => 'Company Address',
];

$userActivities = userActions();

[$startUserRecord] = $userActivities('startUserRecord');

$activity = $startUserRecord(...array_values($fields));

if ($errors = $activity->validate()) {
    throw new InvalidCommand($errors);
}

// Do something with $activity->payload().
```

Note:

- I'm not modifying the payload. You can add a conditioner/sanitizer method that acts on the payload or return the object's properties in some form.
- We're destructuring with the `[$startUserRecord]` line. This allows you to return multiple entries and load them into their own variable names. An example:

  ```
  [$saveUserProfile,$resetUserLogin] = $userActivites('saveUserProfile','resetUserLogin');
  ```
- `$startUserRecord(...array_values($fields))` This is called a spread or splat operation (splat operator: `...` in the invocation), and makes each array item it's own separate argument, in order. I'm getting to that with `array_values()` here, however it's better to pass in an actual array without the keys, to maintain order in all cases.

Here it is put together: https://3v4l.org/sn61Q

This is just a starting point. Change it up, do what you need to, this should give you some idea what you can accomplish.

For instance, you could move the initializers to a `with()` method and "autoload" little closure-based validators that you share within the `userActivities()` function, like a `$validateEmail()` or `$validatePhone()` closures you declare and then `use($validateEmail, ...)` and within that closure `new class($validateEmail, ...)` to share these within an activity's context.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while before today, so here's another refactor with more sanity checks and little nice-to-have features: https://3v4l.org/HbmbM The basic idea is to prototype with indirection and anonymous classes (including invocable closures), which forces you to set things up instead of just a solution-driven (instead of problem-driven), generally procedural, outcome.

Comment: Separated out an abstract class, so it's easier to understand: https://3v4l.org/AYlbS

Comment: thanks for providing this. This is going to take a me a bit to digest and figure everything out.

Comment: What I'm doing is creating a bridging methodology between a fast prototyped, generally procedural code style and the more formulated, first-class OOP systematic approach. My company does a lot of the former, which over time becomes debilitated with technical debt (Chaotic in the Cynefin perceptual framework). The approach above is domain inversion using an Actor Modelesque domain layer that can be forklifted and refactored more readily that straight procedural. Here is a more recent iteration, compare it to the one in the question to see how it was refactored: https://3v4l.org/cdG8r